# How to let iText library support asia character?

Tags: itext

right now i use iText to create a signature.
and when i use .setReason to put the reason of the signature.
It appears that it didn't support chinese.
Can anyone help me to solve this ?
Thanks in advance!
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Set a ASia Font, then it works